Displaying Data in a Column Based Fashion
Cards look like this
I'm having a hard time displaying data in a column based fashion. I am using PHP and CSS.
This is my php code:
<?php 

    include '../DBConnector.php';

    $menuQuery = "SELECT * FROM menu";
    $menuResult = $conn->query($menuQuery);

    if ($menuResult->num_rows > 0) {

    
        while ($row = $menuResult->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/cards.css'> ";
            echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/style.css'>";
            echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/buttons.css'>";

            echo "<div class='cards-container'>";
                echo "<div class ='cards'>";
                    echo "<img class = 'center' src = '" . $row['food_image'] . "' alt = ' " .$row['food_name'] . " '";
                    echo "<div class = 'container'>";
                        echo "<h4><b>" . $row['food_name'] . "</h4><b>";
                        echo "<form action = 'food-view.php' method='post'> 
                            <button type='submit'> Order </button>
                        </form>"; 
                    echo "</div>";                    
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }


    }

?>

and this is my css for the cards:
.cards-container{
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
}

.cards {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;

}

.cards:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    float: left;
}

.container h4{
    margin: 0;
}

.center{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}


table{
    width: 100%;
}

img {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    
}

I tried finding similar questions in this platform, unfortunately, I haven't found any results. Should I use a table? Or do any of you have some insights to what I should do?

First step for easier debugging on this will be to ignore the PHP - the browser doesn't see it, it just sees the HTML and CSS. So create or save some HTML, and edit that directly; then once you have it working, you can go back to the PHP to work out how to generate the right data dynamically. That will also allow you to upload a [mre] here using the "Stack Snippets" functionality.

You don't need to repeat echo you can just use it once also

this is noted..

Are you struggling with the PHP part or the CSS part?

I am struggling with the CSS part. I will try to re-edit this post after transferring my php code into HTML and then do some debugging.

Look into modern layout techniques such as grid or flexbox: https://codepen.io/Chris-Haas-the-builder/pen/GRajjgB

As an aside - I would move the lines echoing the stylesheets outside of the while loop.
